Drag and Drop Block based on the mouse position from outside of the workspace in Blockly (Angular)
I am trying to drag and drop one item as a blockly block from the outside of the blockly workspace into the blockly workspace. I'm encountering difficulty converting the x, y coordinates obtained from the CDK drop event into Blockly coordinates. As a result, the dropped block isn't positioned where I expect it to be, but rather somewhere else. can anyone assist me in obtaining the correct coordinates for the Blockly workspace?
addSelectedFunctionBlockInWorkspace(event: any, blockConfig: any) {
    const dynamicBlock = this.blocklyWorkSpace.newBlock('fn_' + blockConfig.functionId + '_1');
    dynamicBlock.initSvg();
    this.moveDynamicBlock(event, dynamicBlock);
    dynamicBlock.render();
  }


moveDynamicBlock(event: any, dynamicBlock: any) {
    var point = Blockly.browserEvents.mouseToSvg({ clientX: event.dropPoint.x, clientY: event.dropPoint.y } as MouseEvent, this.blocklyWorkSpace.getParentSvg(), this.blocklyWorkSpace.getInverseScreenCTM());
    const metrics = this.blocklyWorkSpace.getMetricsManager().getAbsoluteMetrics();
    let workspaceX = point.x - metrics.left - (this.blocklyWorkSpace.scrollX);
    let workspaceY = point.y - metrics.top - (this.blocklyWorkSpace.scrollY);
    const allBlocks = this.blocklyWorkSpace.getAllBlocks();
    while (!this.isPositionEmpty(workspaceX, workspaceY, allBlocks)) {
      workspaceX += 10;
      workspaceY += 20;
    }
    dynamicBlock.moveBy(workspaceX, workspaceY);
  }


Can you share a complete, runnable [mcve]? Most of these variables are undefined so there's no easy way to help here. Thanks.

Use the CDK for this https://material.angular.io/cdk/drag-drop/overview, it will be much more better and simpler$

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
